# Showing that $(|u_{n}|)$ converges to $|u_{0}|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(u_{n})$ be a convergent sequence converging to $u_{0}$. I want to show that $(|u_{n}|)$ converges to $|u_{0}|$.

**Proof.** We want to show that given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow ||u_{n}| - |u_{0}|| < \epsilon$.

We know that $||u_{n}| - |u_{0}|| < \epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon < |u_{n}| - |u_{0}| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |u_{0}| - \epsilon < |u_{n}| < |u_{0}| + \epsilon$. Showing that $|u_{n}| < |u_{0}| + \epsilon$.

My question is, *how can we deduce, from the last statement, what $N$ would be?* Because the last statement, to me, isn't looking like it converges.

Thanks.

Comment: $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$.

Comment: @geetha290krm So $||u_{n}| - |u_{0}|| \leq |u_{n} - u_{0}| < \epsilon$?